# Matrix product in Latex

Tags: matrices, arrays

I would be immensely happy if I could draw this neat (even if absolutely unoriginal) way to present the matrix product in LaTeX :

[image: Neato matrix product]

*If possible*, I would like a code *quite* simple, that doesn't use tikz, and rather rely on the array environment.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: I could not find this wonderful question and stunning answer by searching for "matrix product by block" with the Stack Exchange search engine. "matrix product by block latex" did not return anything from Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A first approach with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}
  [xdots/line-style={solid,<->},cell-space-limits=10pt]
  {ccccccw{c}{5mm}}
& \hspace*{10mm}  & \hspace*{10mm}  & & \Hdotsfor[shorten=-\arraycolsep]{1}^r & \Hdotsfor[shorten=-\arraycolsep]{1}^{n-r}\\
&   &   & & A'      & B' & \Vdotsfor[shorten=0pt]{1}^{q}\\
&   &   & & C'      & D' & \Vdotsfor[shorten=0pt]{1}^{n-q}\\
& \Hdotsfor[shorten=-\arraycolsep]{1}^q & \Hdotsfor[shorten=-\arraycolsep]{1}^{n-q}\\
& A & B & & AA'+BC' & AB'+BD' & \Vdotsfor[shorten=0pt]{1}^{p}\\
& C & D & & CA'+DC' & CB'+DD' & \Vdotsfor[shorten=0pt]{1}^{n-p}\\
&   &   & & \Hdotsfor[shorten=-\arraycolsep]{1}^{r}  & \Hdotsfor[shorten=-\arraycolsep]{1}^{n-r} \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix({2-5}{3-6})[hvlines]
  \SubMatrix({5-5}{6-6})[hvlines]
  \SubMatrix({5-2}{6-3})[hvlines]
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Excellent. But is it possible to join the arrows where is it necessary?

Comment: @Sebastiano: I've modified my answer.

Comment: But I had already voted for it previously :-)

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you very much!